# VB.Net Form.Close() not working with module

Tags: vb.net

I have a button `btnCancel_Click` click event handler with the following

**1. Form**

```
Public Class frmDatabase
    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Call modApplicationClose(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**2. Module**

```
Module modApp
    Public Sub modApplicationClose(_value As Object)
        _value.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

When I click `btnCancel_Click` form `frmDatabase` not close.

**Error message**

```
StackOverflowException was unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in 
System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Comment: are you sure you want to close the form this way ? can't you just call me.close in the btncancel.click event ?

Comment: i really want to use with module

Comment: Show the stack trace of the exception.  There doesn't seem to be anything in that code to cause a StackOverFlow Exception.

Comment: As a general rule, if you get a stack overflow exception, it's a good idea to take a look at the stack.  You'll usually see a repeating sequence of calls.  If you look through this sequence, you should find a logic error that led to the sequence; fix the logic error, and you fix the stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub modApplicationClose(_value As Form)
    _value.Close()
End Sub
```

Although it does seems a little different to do it the way you want, you must have your reasons for it.
Changing 'Object' to 'Form' worked fine for me. However, even your original worked fine for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Me.close needs to be in the form you're trying to close.

If you need to perform some logic somewhere else to decide if the form close is OK, you can pass back a boolean:

```
if modApplicationClose(param, param, etc) then
    me.close()
end if
```